# Router path not matched using Vue 3 + Vite

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs3, amazon-cognito, vite

I am trying to make a Vue 3 project with Vite, that checks if user is logged in with AWS Cognito before entering to main page.

This is my router.js:

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'
import store from '../store';
import auth from '../auth';
import url from 'url'


function requireAuth(to, from, next) {
  if (!auth.auth.isUserSignedIn()) {
    next({
      path: '/check-login',
      query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
    });
  } else {
    console.log("User already logged in");
    if(store.getters.token==null) {
      store.commit('setToken', auth.auth.signInUserSession.getIdToken().jwtToken);
    }
    next();
  }
}

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView,
    beforeEnter: requireAuth
  },
  {
    path: '/check-login', beforeEnter: () => {
      auth.auth.getSession();
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/login*', beforeEnter: async () => {
      let currUrl = window.location.href;
      const queryObject = url.parse(currUrl,true);
      const query = queryObject.hash.replace("#", "").split("&");
      let id_token = "";
      for(let i=0; i<query.length; i++){
        if(query[i].indexOf("id_token")>-1) {
          id_token = query[i];
          id_token = id_token.replace("id_token=", "");
          break;
        }
      }
      if(id_token){
        console.log("Setting token");
        store.commit('setToken', id_token);
      }
      await auth.auth.parseCognitoWebResponse(currUrl);
      goHome();
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/logout',  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      auth.logout();
      next();
    }
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})


function goHome() {
  router.push("/");
}

export default router
```

When I run the project using **npm run dev** the following warning appears:

> [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/check-login?redirect=/"

I've tried to load manually other routes like **login** but same result. It seems that it doesn't recognize my routes (except Home), maybe because there is something wrong in the definition, but I can't find what it is...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found what was wrong. I had to include a component in every route to be detected well.

What I did is create a blank view with only a **route-view** inside.